# Getting values using loop index ColdFusion 9

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Is it possible to get value of the parameters using loop index in ColdFusion 9. To be clear let me give an example.

Let's say we are getting the parameters from html text boxes. There are three text boxes and named text_1, text_2, text_3.

So without using loop, there is no problem. We can add the values to DB, but for three text boxes we need to write three insert query like:

```
insert into #application.schema#.#application.table#
    (text_value)
    values
    (
    <cfqueryparam value="#attributes.props.text_1#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
    )
insert into #application.schema#.#application.table#
    (text_value)
    values
    (
    <cfqueryparam value="#attributes.props.text_2#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
    )
insert into #application.schema#.#application.table#
    (text_value)
    values
    (
    <cfqueryparam value="#attributes.props.text_3#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
    )
```

My question is that, Is there any change to do it using loop? Something like:

```
<cfloop from="1" to="3" index="i">
   <cfquery name="insertTextBoxes" datasource="#application.dsn#" timeout="30">
        insert into #application.schema#.#application.table#
        (text_value)
        values
        (
        <cfqueryparam value="#attributes.props.text_#i##" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
        )       
   </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

I tried various ways but could't solve it. I can not get the value using loop index. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: All you need is associative array notation, `structName["someStaticName_"& counterVariable ]`, ie `attributes.props["text_"& i ]`.  Do a search on dynamic form variables. There are a ton of examples.

Comment: Voting to reopen.  The other question refers to the form scope.  This one refers to a convoluted structure.

Comment: @Leigh that what I was looking for. Thank you so much! It reduced the code, and the code is more readable now.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot nest octothorpic values like that. To concatenate in CFM, you need to do put them side by side, or use the `&` concat operator.

```
<cfqueryparam value="#attributes.props.text_##i#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
```

HOWEVER! THE ABOVE IS WRONG! Because `#attributes.props.text_#` is not a real variable, this will break.

The best thing for you to do is loop properly, over the attributes object!

```
<cfloop collection="#attributes.props#" item="item">
    <cfquery name="insertTextBoxes" datasource="#application.dsn#" timeout="30">
        INSERT INTO #application.schema#.#application.table# (text_value)
        VALUES (
            <cfqueryparam value="#item#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
        )       
   </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

This way (I need to review my syntax, but study the logic!) will avoid these pesky concat issues, and directly loop over these attribute properties nice and neat like.

Comment: shouldn't the value in your queryparam be `attributes.props[item]` ?

Comment: Right now the issue is that attributes.props doesn't contain only text_ values, it has some other values which I don't want to insert them as a text_value.

Comment: then in the loop also check if it starts with `text_`

Comment: Sorry for the not clear explaining, to be clear I just gave a small example. But in the insert, we also have other parameters. Those are also coming from html text boxes. If it's attributes.props.text_2 it also need to insert attributes.props.xyz_2 and attributes.props.abc_2. Again if text_3, need to insert xyz_3, abc_3 too.